# How to use an imported variable outside of a component function in React useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a variable likedImages that is imported from another file in a useEffect hook inside a React component, but I am running into issues.

When I try to include it in the dependency array, I get a warning saying that it's an unnecessary dependency, which I am assuming it means likedImages dependency is useless. However, when I exclude it from the dependency array, the useEffect hook doesn't run when likedImages changes.

I can't move the import statement inside the component function as imports must always be at the top of the file.

What's the best way to use likedImages in the useEffect hook to make it run every time likedImages changes?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { likedImages } from './Cat.js';

const LikeScreen = () => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLiked(likedImages);
  }, [likedImages]);

  console.log('Liked:', liked);
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Liked Page</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default LikeScreen;
```

Comment: you can't use it like this, instead try to send them as props

Comment: What does `likedImages` include?

Comment: If liked images doesn’t expose an API that allows you to subscribe to it/listen for changes to it, then there’s nothing you can do here.

Comment: I cant send it as props as the component I import this from is not a parent of this component. Is it maybe possible to pass props to a child component without rendering its contents, this way I can pass props to my component.

Comment: @Rajesh Im creating a cat image gallery so it contains an array of cat img urls.

Comment: You can create a custom hook that returns this array. This way you can tie it to you useEffect

Answer (score -1):

You can send it like props

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const LikeScreen = (props) => {
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLiked(props.likedImages);
  }, [props.likedImages]);

  console.log('Liked:', liked);
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Liked Page</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default LikeScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```